# Get credential in nodejs google sheet v4

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-api

I'm following this tutorial https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs and I'm able to read and update my sheet.

I'd like to get the credential in order to pass more parameters to my function.

```
authorize(JSON.parse(content), listMajors);
```

How can I pass 1 more parameter to listMajor?
Or How can I get `auth` to pass my own function like listMajors?

```
function listMajors(auth) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, in order to add one more parameter to the arguments in `listMajors`, how about using `call` and/or `apply`?

#### Using `call`:

```
authorize(JSON.parse(content), (auth) => listMajors.call(this, auth, "additionalParameter"));  // or listMajors.call(null, auth, "additionalParameter")
```

#### Using `apply`:

```
authorize(JSON.parse(content), (auth) => listMajors.apply(this, [auth, "additionalParameter"]));  // or listMajors.apply(null, [auth, "additionalParameter"])
```

#### Note:

- In above modification, the arguments can be used like `function listMajors(auth, parameter){}`.

#### References:

- [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)
- [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

### Added:

I add 2 other methods.

#### 1. Using function:

```
authorize(JSON.parse(content), (auth) => listMajors(auth, "additionalParameter"));
```

In this case, the arguments can be used like `function listMajors(auth, parameter){}`.

#### 2. Using `bind`:

```
authorize(JSON.parse(content), listMajors.bind(this, "additionalParameter"));  // or listMajors.bind(null, "additionalParameter")
```

In this case, the arguments can be used like `function listMajors(parameter, auth){}`.

#### Reference:

- [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)